# Get first minimum free integer key/id in array of integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

Suppose i have some key array:

```
var idlist= [1, 2, 3, 6];
```

after I was created new object, I need new key/id for it, so i need somethink like this:

```
fucntion getFirstFreeKey(keylist){
???
}
```

in my example *getFirstFreeKey(idlist)* will return 4.

Comment: `{1, 2, 3, 6}` This is not a valid array or an object.

Comment: is getFirstFreeKey returning count of elements ?

Comment: How do you defined `free`?

Comment: "first free" is minimum integer that is not in existing keyId array in [1,2,3,6] case it is 4

Comment: Your are right Thanga. It's should be in [...] not in {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proposal works with [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

> The `every()` method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The algorithm looks for consecutive numbers and returns the last one, incremented by one, if a gap is found.

```js
function free(array, start) {
    array.every(function (a) {
        if (start === a) {
            start = a + 1;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return start;
}

document.write(free([1, 2, 3, 6], 1) + '<br>'); // 4
document.write(free([1, 2, 3, 4], 1) + '<br>'); // 5
document.write(free([2, 3, 4], 1) + '<br>');    // 1
document.write(free([], 1) + '<br>');           // 1
```

Comment: what is the time complexity of this algorithm? O(n) ?

Comment: Isn't there some way to achieve this in O(log n)? Binary Search?

Comment: short no. too much overhead.

Comment: your solution is for also only for sorted arrays, it's enough to add, array.sort() to your solution. Working perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is ordered and you need the next free sequential number:

```
var freeNum;

for(var i = 0; i < idlist.Length; i++)
{
    if(idList[i] != i + 1)
    {
         freeNum = i + 1;
         break;
    }
}

return freeNum;
```

Comment: Assuming your list is ordered/sorted and you need the next free sequential number: